# necessary and sufficient condition for a graph to have 2-colorable line graph

Tags: graph-theory

I know about a every even cyclic graph have 2-colorable line graph ,because the line graph for cycle is a cycle.and even cycle graph is 2-colorable .but i can not determine whole graph that have 2-colorabe line graph . and necessary and sufficient condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another necessary condition is for the original graph $G$ to have maximum degree $2$. If $G$ has a vertex of degree $k \ge 3$, the edges out of that vertex correspond to a clique of size $k$ in the line graph. Any proper coloring of that clique needs at least $k$ colors; for $k\ge 3$, it won't be $2$-colorable.

If $G$ has maximum degree $2$, then it consists of several components, which are either:

- Paths, whose line graph is also a path, and therefore $2$-colorable, or
- Cycles, which you already know everything about.

Putting all this together, you can write down a condition on $G$ that is both necessary and sufficient.